# Dynamic change to item in ASP.NET C# without postback?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, postback

In ASP.NET C#, I have a checkbox and a text box.  I would like to make the text box's visibility dependany upon the checkbox (i.e. if the box is checked, the text box is visible, and if it is not checked, the text box is hidden), but I would like it done "immediately" as opposed to through a postback.  Is this possible?

Comment: That's what javascript is for.

Comment: FYI, it's "ASP.NET", not "ASP".

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a client side script in javascript that handles this behavior.
If you don't know what's javascript google it.

Comment: "If you don't know what's javascript google it" - You aren't being very helpful with that statement.

Comment: @Jordan Knowing the basics of java script is very important for a new web developer, I think this is the best way to help.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mycheckbox').change(function() {
    $('.mycheckbox').is(':checked') ? $('.mytextbox').show() : $('.mytextbox').hide();
  });
});
```

where `mycheckbox` and `mytextbox` are classes for your inputs.

Or you can use `ClientID`:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cb" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#<%= cb.ClientID %>').change(function() {
    $('#<%= cb.ClientID %>').is(':checked') ? $('#<%= txt.ClientID %>').show() : $('#<%= txt.ClientID %>').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's important to note that if your using jquery, a benefit exists, because of the compatibility between different browsers and the behavior staying consistent.